# Redux - smart components - how do you handle asynchronous action before mounting a component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I'm building a React/Redux app, querying an API to fetch data about users.

I am trying to reuse the tutorial here:
https://rackt.org/redux/docs/advanced/ExampleRedditAPI.html

Let's say I have a container component UserPage which displays information for a given user:

```
class UserPage extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchUser(this.props.user.id));
  }

  render() {
    <UserProfile name={this.props.user.name} />
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    user: _.find(state.users, (user) => user.id == ownProps.params.userId)),
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    dispatch
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserPage);
```

To get the current user, I make an API call:
`GET /api/users/:userId`

My problem is that when initializing the Component, the property user does not necessarily exists.

Therefore, an error pops `can't call property name on undefined`.

How do you handle your initial component state?
Do you rely on `componentWillReceiveProps` to refresh your UI?
Are you using a `isFetching` property?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a conditional.

```
class UserPage extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(fetchUser(this.props.user.id));
    }

    renderUser() {
        if (this.props.user) {
            return (
                <UserProfile name={this.props.user.name} />
            )
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>{this.renderUser()}</div>
        )
    }
}
```

As you mention, you might want to have an "isFetching" property and render a spinner or something when true.